# How to include php code which comes from php variable to php file?

Tags: php

I have php editor.The php code in the editor go to this php variable: `$redux_demo['opt-ace-editor-php']`. How can I write this variable to php file?

For example, I insert the css code come from css editor like this:

```
 echo '<style type="text/css">'.$redux_demo['opt-ace-editor-css'].'</style>';
```

Also, `<?php` tag may can be use top of code in editor or may not.So, the code must work in two scenerio.

So, I wonder can I use `<?php` tag after another? Or can I use `<?php` tag in echo function?

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is different from those code running inside the browser. PHP code runs in your server.

If you are sure you want to write code into PHP file. Try use:

```
file_put_contents("path/to/php/file.php",$content);
```

And make sure, for every PHP file, a  tag should be put at the beginning, like:

```
file_put_contents("path/to/php/file.php","<?php\n$content");
```

BTW, be alert and careful when write PHP file dynamically, it may introduce security issue by doing this.

Comment: @Farukrıza - Maybe you will have to look it at both ways. Have you clarified to 100% what you want?